# How to regulate the decimals in numbers placed above barplots?

Tags: pgfplots

I am using the latex package "pgfplots" for producing x-barplots. In these plots the height of each bar is placed as a number to the right of the bar, as shown here:

[image]

The code for producing these barplot is given below. Includet in this code is a datafile with x and y numbers, called "data1.dat". My concern is how to regulate the number of decimals shown in the figure. For instance, in the datafile the y-value 1 has the x-value 15.1234, but this number is shown as "15.12" in the figure. More specifically:

(1) How do I set the number of decimals to a specific value, for instance one?

(2) How can I prevent 0.049 to be written 4.9*10-2, but instead as "0.0" if I want one decimal?

(3) How do I  make 12.0 to be written as "12.0" instead of "12" as in the figure?

(4) is it possible to exchange 0.049 in the datafile with  "<0.05" so that "< 0.05" is shown in the figure?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{
compat=newest, 
    width=6cm,
    height=4cm, 
    xtick align =outside,
    xtick pos = both,
    xticklabel pos =lower,
    xmin=-5,
    xmax = 105,     
    ytick align = outside,   
    ytick pos = left, 
    yticklabel pos=left,  
    ymin =0,
    ymax = 5,    
    ytick=data,
    xbar,  
    nodes near coords,  
    every node near coord/.append style = {anchor=west},
}

\begin{document}

% Measurements 
\begin{filecontents}{data1.dat}
  yvalue         xvalue   
  1                  15.1234   
  2                  20.5678     
  3                  12.0       
  4                 0.049     
\end{filecontents}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    yticklabels from table={data1.dat}{yvalue},  
    xlabel = {x},
    ylabel = {y},
   every axis y label/.style = {at={(yticklabel cs:0.5)}, rotate=0,anchor =east},
    bar width=4pt,  
]
\addplot table [
    y=yvalue,
    x=xvalue, 
] {data1.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As percusse said in the comment, you can force fixed point notation with a specified precision by setting `/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/precision=1` in the `every node near coord/.append style`. To make sure that there is always one decimal, even if it is zero, you also need to add `/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill`.

The last request is trickier, here you need to test the value and then decide what to do with it. This is most easily done using the optional argument of `nodes near coords`. By default, this value is `nodes near coords=\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}`, where `\pgfmathprintnumber` takes care of applying all the formatting options we specified, and `\pgfplotspointmeta` contains the `meta` value, which defaults to the `x` value in an `xbar` plot, or the `y` value in most other plot types.

What we want to do is check whether `\pgfplotspointmeta` is less than `0.05`, and print the string `$<0.05$` if it is, and `\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}` otherwise. The intuitive thing to do would be to use `\ifdim\pgfplotspointmeta pt<0.05pt ... \else ... \fi`, but that doesn't work because `\pgfplotspointmeta` contains a floating point number (which looks like `1Y4.9e-2]`), causing `\ifdim` to stumble. The best approach here is to switch on the `fpu` library (which has a much greater number range than pure LaTeX arithmetic), do the comparison using `\pgfmathparse`, convert the result of the comparison (which is either `1` or `0`) to a "normal" fixed point number, switch off the `fpu` library (otherwise things will break later on), and use `\ifdim` on the converted result of the comparison.

So if you use

```
nodes near coords={%
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}% Switch on the fpu library
    \pgfmathparse{\pgfplotspointmeta<0.05}% Do the comparison
    \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult}% convert the result to fixed point
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}% switch off the fpu library
    \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=1pt % If the condition was true...
            $<0.05$
    \else 
            \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}     
    \fi
}
```

you will get

[image]

---

Here's the complete code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{
compat=newest, 
    width=6cm,
    height=4cm, 
    xtick align =outside,
    xtick pos = both,
    xticklabel pos =lower,
    xmin=-5,
    xmax = 105,     
    ytick align = outside,   
    ytick pos = left, 
    yticklabel pos=left,  
    ymin =0,
    ymax = 5,    
    ytick=data,
    xbar,  
    nodes near coords={%
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}%
        \pgfmathparse{\pgfplotspointmeta<0.05}%
        \pgfmathfloattofixed{\pgfmathresult}%
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
        \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=1pt
            $<0.05$
        \else 
            \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}     
        \fi
        },  
    every node near coord/.append style = {
        anchor=west,
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill,
        precision=1,
    },
}

\begin{document}

% Measurements 
\begin{filecontents}{data1.dat}
  yvalue         xvalue   
  1                  15.1234   
  2                  20.5678     
  3                  12.0       
  4                 0.049     
\end{filecontents}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    yticklabels from table={data1.dat}{yvalue},  
    xlabel = {x},
    ylabel = {y},
   every axis y label/.style = {at={(yticklabel cs:0.5)}, rotate=0,anchor =east},
    bar width=4pt,  
]
\addplot table [
    y=yvalue,
    x=xvalue, 
] {data1.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah I was fiddling with `scatter/@pre marker code/.prefix code={`. That's why it didn't work!

Comment: Oh yeah, that's a hard one to work with. Internally, `nodes near coords` uses that I think, shielding you from the nitty gritty of `@pre marker code`.

Comment: Bravo, that works nice!